# Laravel 5.3 & Crypt - invalid payload

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5

I have an app I wrote in Laravel 5.23. In it I am encrypting certain sensitive user data before I store in a table using:

```
'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
```

The field's migration is:

```
$table->string('field_account_name')->nullable();
```

I have mutators set up in the class to do this:

```
public function getFieldAccountNameClearAttribute($value)
{
    if ($this->field_account_name) {
        try {
            return Crypt::decrypt($this->field_account_name);
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            return 'INVALID';
        }
    } else {
        return $this->field_account_name;
    }
}
```

and

```
public function setFieldAccountNameClearAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['field_account_name'] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
}
```

This has been working for a long time perfectly but a user waived their magic a week ago and triggered:

```
Exception 'ErrorException' with message 'The payload is invalid
```

I have managed to replicate the issue by placing special characters (such as `'`) in the field as part of a long string with spaces.

The date is encrypted and stored but it fails when retrieved.

Is there characters I should exclude from the encryption at the front end to avoid this? I cannot find an answer to this.

Or perhaps the field should be `text` instead of string?

Comment: you should use `text` instead of `varchar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be related to the amount of data you're trying to encrypt and how it's stored in the database. If the encrypted text exceeds 255 characters, it will get truncated when it's added to the database, which means it's cannot be decrypted.

You should update your existing migration to:

```
$table->text('field_account_name')->nullable();
```

or use the following in a new migration:

```
$table->text('field_account_name')->nullable()->change();
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the fields to `TEXT` and all ok now.